# Are static class members static in Java?

Tags: java, static

In the below code, are `b` and `show` inherently static?

```
public class A {
    public static class B {
        private int b = 0;
        public void show() {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An instance of `B` has no implicit reference to an instance of `A`

Comment: Thanks all for such detailed answers. However I could only accept one even though all were informative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `static` keyword in your code example means that instances of B can be created without an instance of A.

If `B` was not static:

- Instances would have an implicit reference to an instance of `A`.
- The only way to create them would be to use `new B()` inside class `A`, or using syntax like `new A().new B()`.
- Methods in `B` **can** refer to `A.this` (the implicit reference to an instance of `A`).
- Methods in `B` **can** refer to `A.this.someField` (using that implicit reference).
- Methods in `B` **can** call instance (non-static) methods in `A`.

However, because `B` is static:

- Instances do not have a reference to an instance of `A` - you don't need an `A` to create a `B`.
- Instances can be created using `new A.B()` (or just `new B()` from within in class `A`)
- Methods in `B` **cannot** refer to `A.this`.
- Methods in `B` **cannot** access fields in A (unless passed in as a parameter).
- Methods in `B` **cannot** call instance (non-static) methods in `A`.

Answer (score 9):

No they aren't `static`. You need to create an instance of `B` to access them.

Answer (score 2):

They are not static. They are instance fields in B.
Meaning you need to have an instance of B to get/set them.
B is static in A but that does not make those fields of B static.
You can create many instances of B without any reference to A.
So B is static class in A but the same is not true for B's instance fields.

Comment: How are they `static` with respect to `A`. In fact you shouldn't even talk about this wrt `A`, as they are the member of class `B`.

Comment: Because B is static class in A.

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly this makes the fields in `B` `static`?

Comment: @peter Yeah that is true, but saying they are `static` with respect to `A` gives an impression that you can actually do `A.B.b`, which you can't.

Comment: I meant you can do: A.b1.b and A.b2.b. But yes, when I think more about it - you have right.

Answer (score 1):

The static keyword has two meanings that are actually quite different and that can be confusing.

Static on a variable/method means that it exists at the class level, not the instance level. This means that you only have one copy of that variable/method no matter how many instances of the class you create.

Static on an inner class though just means that the class does not depend upon its outer class. In your example you can create a `new B()` without having an `A`. If you didn't have the static keyword on the class you could not create a `new B()` unless it was within an instance of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

B is a static inner class of A.
Need to instantiate B.

```
A.B innerObject = new A.B();
innerObject.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The identifier `static` has a specific purpose here that many people don't immediately grasp. I'm going to take your code and change it a bit.

```
public class A {
    private int a;
    public A(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public class B {
        public void show() {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what's happening in class `B`? Because `B` is a non-static class, it has access to other non-static members in class `A`. Essentially, it states that every class `A` object has their own flavor of class `B` objects, even thought they are functionally the same. For us to get that same behavior if `B` was a static class:

```
public class A {
    private int a;
    public A(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getA() { return a;  }

    public static class B {
        public void show(A a) {
            System.out.println(a.getA());
        }
    }
}
```

Here, this implies that the flavor of `B` objects doesn't change depending on which `A` object created it. The `B` class is static so that it cannot access non-static members of the `A` class object that created it and must access those members explicitly from whichever `A` object it wants to interact with.

In the previous implementation, a `B` object would seamlessly access fields and non-static methods of the `A` object that created it.

These are two different behaviors and often it's clear exactly which one fits your objective.